# Some meshes follow the armature and some don't

Tags: rigging

I'm new to blender and hoping to get some help! I'm playing around with the animal crossing models available on the-models-resource. The models are already rigged. I'm able to get the clothing and shoes meshes to move with the body by selecting the clothing mesh > modifier properties > set the body's armature to be the one mesh deforms with. This works for clothing and shoes. For some reason it does not work with hair and headgear, does anybody know why?

[image]

Dress and shoes working as intended

[image]

Hair and hat don't follow even though all settings are the same...

Here's the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/61aa6f7e31bf47f3a17ba91ce420e41b

Comment: a quick fix would be to select the hat, go in Edit mode, select all the vertices, go in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, change the name of Root to Root.001, which is the name of the bone that is supposed to control it, then click Assign, and the hat should follow. But more generally you'd better follow some tutorials on rigging because it would make it easier to understand how it works, for example the rigging here is a bit messy, probably because it comes from a game that has its own system, so it's going to be tedious to explain the whole thing.

Comment: @moonboots U ARE A LIFESAVER!!!!! It works perfectly thank you so so much!!!

Comment: Hannah, if this has answered your question, please consider accepting moonboot's answer. Click on the green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rigging seems messy, probably because it comes from a game that has its own system, so it would take too long to fix it all, but a quick fix for the hat for example: Go in *Edit* mode, select all the vertices, go in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, change the name of *Root* to *Root.001*, which is the name of the bone that is supposed to control it, then click *Assign*.